# What methods does my c++ executable actually use

Tags: c++, g++

I have an executable compiled with g++ that links in about 50 static libraries (on top of a bunch of system libraries). I'd like to know which methods in those libraries are being used, or even more important which methods will never be called.

Is there a tool and/or compiler flag that will provide this?

Comment: `Dependency Walker` does what you need but for linked DLLs. I doubt there is way to do the same for statically linked libs but I might be wrong. http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: You can use `valgrind`'s `callgrind` to get a call-graph of the functions and libs actually used in your application *and* for some specific control flow. To see the dynamically linked dependencies of your application, use `ldd`.

Comment: @DanielSaska: Since when does dep walker process ELF executables? ;) Just found this: http://code.google.com/p/elf-dependency-walker/

Comment: maybe [gcov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gcov) can help you if you can recompile the libs. it's a nice tool and part of the [gcc tools](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/).

Comment: "which methods will never be called" --- this question is equivalent to the halting problem, so no.

Comment: @n.m. Beat me to it. A better way to phrase the question would be, _"Which methods are not referenced"_ - that is a much harder task than _"Which methods are referenced"_ since the former requires every single method in the 50 static libraries to be enumerated.

Comment: @n.m - i guess, reference to Halting problem deserves an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nm` tool in Linux\UNIX (at least when compiled with -g)

Since you are using static libs ONLY THE REFERENCED METHODS from the libraries will be added to your executable

usage like:

```
nm <your executable with debug info>
```

you can also try to read man page;

```
man nm
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly mean but if you want to get the functions that are not referenced, there are some compiler options.

**-ffunction-sections**
would tell the compiler to place each function into its own section in the obj file.

then at link time **--gc-sections**  and **--print-gc-sections** would do garbage collection of unused sections(functions) and also list the result.

You may want to build all your static libraries to have a complete list.